# Repeating a background on Android

Tags: android, css

I have a mobile responsive theme that I have created, and it works great.. On everything except android. The background image loads and looks fine, but it does not render on parts of the site that are not in view when the page is loaded. Any time you scroll down the page, the background is white. The code that I have at this time is:

```
body
{

 background: url('images/MobileBack.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I have tried some other variations of this declaration, but to no avail. Is there a way to load the background on Android using just CSS, or do I have to delve deeper? (PS. it works fine on iPhones and iPads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the issue was the `center center fixed` appendage to the `background` declaration.

Comment: I think it was just the fixed attachment that caused the issue, not the center positioning.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use media query to fix this problem

```
@media screen {
background: url('images/MobileBack.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

hope it works if not then if you don't mind let me see its screen shot

Comment: I have tried placing it within this media query:  `@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px)`

Comment: yup, see selected answer above, i needed to remove the `center center fixed` declaration